# Как исправить ошибку SyntaxError:?

Tags: php, javascript

Эта ошибка появляется при сохранении(редактировании) новости.
Файл php не знаю как показать. Он довольно не маленький.

```
SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'
```

Может где-то здесь ошибка

```
    $script .= "if(document.entryform.short_story.value == '' || document.entryform.title.value == ''){ alert('$lang[add_err_7]'); }
    if( $config['allow_site_wysiwyg'] == "yes" ) $script .= "<form method=post name=\"entryform\" id=\"entryform\" onsubmit=\"document.getElementById('short_story').value = tinyMCE.get('short_story').getContent(); document.getElementById('full_story').value = tinyMCE.get('full_story').getContent(); if(document.entryform.title.value == '' || document.entryform.short_story.value == ''){alert('$lang[add_err_7]');return false}\" action=\"\">";
    else $script .= "<form method=post name=\"entryform\" id=\"entryform\" onsubmit=\"if(document.entryform.title.value == '' || document.entryform.short_story.value == ''){alert('$lang[add_err_7]');return false}\" action=\"\">";
```

Comment: кроме этого сообщения там должно быть указание строки где это произошло, ну и собственно нужна эта самая строка

Comment: Больше ничего не написано

Comment: где ты видишь эту ошибку?

Comment: В консоли еще такая есть `TypeError: document.entryform.short_story is undefined`

Comment: справа от текста ошибки указана строка в коде, на которой эта ошибка произошла

Comment: что это за код?

Comment: Это я в файле php по этой ошибке `entryform.short_story` нашел

Comment: Ну и стоит посмотреть конечную строку, которая получается, и заметить, что посреди javascript кода вдруг появляется html `<form`   и это вполне логично все падает

Comment: Это одна из причин, почему не стоит все собирать в строке. а лучше воспользоваться какими-нибудь шаблонизаторами

Comment: Чего с этим делать?

Answer (score 2):

первую строку

> $script .= "if(document.entryform.short_story.value == '' ||
>   document.entryform.title.value == ''){ alert('$lang[add_err_7]'); }

замените на

> $script .= "if(document.entryform.short_story.value == '' ||
>   document.entryform.title.value == ''){ alert('$lang[add_err_7]'); }";

Comment: Кавычка закрывается чуть дальше `$script .= "if(document.entryform.short_story.value == '' || document.entryform.title.value == ''){ alert('$lang[add_err_7]'); };
    else{
        dd=window.open('','prv','height=400,width=750,resizable=0,scrollbars=1')
        document.entryform.mod.value='preview';document.entryform.action='{$config['http_home_url']}engine/preview.php';document.entryform.target='prv'
        document.entryform.submit();dd.focus()
        setTimeout(\"document.entryform.mod.value='addnews';document.entryform.action='';document.entryform.target='_self'\",500)
    }
}";`

Comment: @steep в приведенном в вопросе коде, у Вас ошибка из-за этого лезет `if( $config['allow_site_wysiwyg'] == "yes" ) $script .= "<form method=post`, конкретно в месте `= "<form` Вы закрываете кавычки и далее идет голый код `<form ...`. без присвоения к какой-либо переменной.

Comment: @steep и указанный Вами код в комментарии к ответу отличается от кода, указанного Вами в вопросе. Рекомендуем обновить вопрос включив в него проблемные файлы, т.к. без этого помочь Вам весьма затруднительно.

Answer (score 1):

Была пропущена закрывающая ковычка в первой строчке

```
$script .= "if(document.entryform.short_story.value == '' || document.entryform.title.value == ''){ alert('$lang[add_err_7]'); }";
if( $config['allow_site_wysiwyg'] == "yes" ) {
    $script .= "<form method=post name=\"entryform\" id=\"entryform\" onsubmit=\"document.getElementById('short_story').value = tinyMCE.get('short_story').getContent(); document.getElementById('full_story').value = tinyMCE.get('full_story').getContent(); if(document.entryform.title.value == '' || document.entryform.short_story.value == ''){alert('$lang[add_err_7]');return false}\" action=\"\">";
} else {
    $script .= "<form method=post name=\"entryform\" id=\"entryform\" onsubmit=\"if(document.entryform.title.value == '' || document.entryform.short_story.value == ''){alert('$lang[add_err_7]');return false}\" action=\"\">";
}
```

Comment: а [первый ответ](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/573806/191745) Вы не видите?